# What is a 両県 (as seen in newspapers)?

Tags: words

I've seen this a couple of times in newspapers. For example:

> ....は山口、広島**両県**の....

I can't find it in any dictionary. My gut feeling is that it indicates a sort of union between the two prefectures, in this case between Yamaguchi and Hiroshima. Can someone confirm or clarify this?

Comment: 両~ = both, no? Like... 両足=both legs, 両極=both poles, 両端=both ends, 両サイド=both sides...（↓笑！わたしも今気づいた）

Comment: Wouldn't this just mean "both prefectures"? Like 両手 - both hands. (edit: I see Chocolate got there 6 seconds before me :D)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

両〜 is a prefix meaning "both". In this case "both prefectures".

[Here](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%B8%A1&eng=&dict=edict) are some other examples of its usage, from EDICT via jisho.org.

Comment: Oh, yeah that makes a lot of sense...something about it just threw me off. I think having the two names first, I don't know. Thanks though :)